# Correct terminology of Expired & Damaged Raw Materials/ Cosmetics Industry

Tags: grammaticality

I need the correct terminology for items/Raw materials damaged, expired, and not for use or recycling anymore specifically in storing system inventory, etc

I have suggested:

> Spoilage Stock Inventory

Does this work for official use and professional business reporting?

Comment: If by "official use and professional business reporting" you mean things like tax reporting and official company accounts, you're probably better speaking to a tax lawyer or accountant.

Comment: *Inventory breakage*, also called *inventory shortage*, covers these situations.

Comment: Someone with expertise in your industry may know a specific term commonly used there.

Comment: I can't speak for the cosmetic industry, but the food industry definitely favors spoiled.  Manufacturing seems to use spoilage, wastage, rejects, defects, and I'm sure a lot of others.

Comment: So you're storing waste instead of disposing of it?